# how to copy and insert a row in same table for oracle db

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I have a table with fields like pmk01,pmk02,...pmk100 and pmk01,pmk02 as index.
Now I want to copy a line in the table, modify the index and insert into the table. how to do it. I heared I can achieve this using Resultset. but I wonder if the resultset SQL statement like select pmk01,...pmk100 from pmk. How does it deal with empty field in resultset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t(pmk01, pmk02, ... pmk100)
    select 0 as pk01, 0 as pmk02, pmk03, . . .
    from t;
```